# How to Find UUID by String with Like in typeorm querybuilder?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, sql-like, uuid

I am trying to create query with `Typeorm QueryBuilder`. I am making api for searching from table. So I want to match `id: uuid` with `like` operator in it.  I am using `postgres` database.

query :

```
const query = entity.createQueryBuilder()
              .select("id, name")
              .where("id like :id", { id: "%4fd56%" })
```

But Id is auto generated uuid and can't match with like operator.
Do you guys have any idea, how can I achieve it ? please guide me.

Comment: is this `id` column a primary key?

Comment: Yes @MicaelLevi, It's a @primaryGeneratedColumn()

Comment: then use `.whereInIds`